# Is it possible to share what you see with a other device in the same room?

Tags: google-project-tango

Is it possible to see the same object concurrently on multiple devices.

For example, a sofa in the room.
Or a jenga tower which you can play with between two Tango devices?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is not an included feature of the Tango SDK.

I can reccommend something like [Photon](https://www.photonengine.com/en/PUN) to do the talking between devices for you.
There are also many other alternatives.